# timerfd_create produces Too many open files error

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, epoll

I need more than 9990 file descriptors produced by timerfd_create for an event based application and get an EMFILE "too many open files".

So I adapted the usual parameters and limitations:

**sys.fs.file-max** is 1000000 so the system wide limit should not be an issue. **sys.fs.nr_open** is 1048576 so my comparatively large value of file-max should still be considered valid. The per user limits in limits.conf is 1000000 and this is confirmed by **ulimit -n** which shows 1000000.

What am I missing ??

This is on a 2.6.32-5-amd64 kernel running inside a VirtualBox ontop of Windows XP on iCore 7.

**EDIT:** Embarassing. I link with some code which does a setrlimit of this value to a lower value...so I am lowering the per process limit myself. Discovered this by chance - may the hint be useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux then you can find a command named ulimit. There are several options might help you, such as:

```
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

So, `ulimit -u` will give you the power of running unlimited process for a specific user